# How can we use bucket4j spring boot starter with spring cloud gateway?

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway, rate-limiting, bucket4j

I've to rate limit users based on their plans and endpoints. Unfortuntely, there is no built in solutions in spring cloud gateway with lettuce redis client. I came across [bucket4j-spring boot starter](https://github.com/MarcGiffing/bucket4j-spring-boot-starter). But I couldn't find examples about it. I need to customize with java. But their docs provide examples in which configurations are made through yml files.
I want flexible solution so that if user upgrade plan then his rate limiting also adjusted accordingly. Bucket4j provides solution to replace configuration but how can i do that?
Should i use bucket4j spring boot starter or customize bucket4j myself.

I tried to configure redisRateLimiter of spring cloud gateway. but couldn't get results. I need to use lettuce redis client.